# How deep into a Matrix field type can I go with IF statements?

Tags: matrix, assets, playa, ifelse

Bear with me as I explain my setup...

I have a channel called Speaker and a channel field called `speaker_media` that is a matrix field type. Inside the matrix I have a channel field for `speaker_audio`, `speaker_video`, `speaker_photos`. the Speaker entry is set up with the speaker's name, title, company, bio, and topic and is used in promotional material leading up to the event.

I have another channel called Multimedia. Multimedia entries might be for a speaker event and they might not be. If they are, I have a channel field called `speaker_import`. It's a Playa field type that allows the user (me) to define a relationship between this Multimedia entry and a single Speaker entry, since the Speaker entry will always come before the Multimedia entry (we don't have multimedia until after the event, duh!). When the `speaker_import` field is not empty, my template grabs all the relevant info from the Speaker entry and displays it, meaning that I don't have to duplicate a bunch of information like `media_description` (`speaker_bio`), `media_subtitle` (`speaker_topic`), and more.

So my question...

When I get to the raw source portion of the Multimedia entry, I want to be able to automatically pull the speaker media in if it's defined. But since that media is a couple levels deep on the Speaker entry (`speaker_import` > `speaker_media` > `speaker_audio`), how can I do this with an IF statement? Here is what I have so far. It's wrong and I know that, but hopefully seeing it will assist in making it NOT wrong.

```
{if speaker_import}
    {speaker_import}
        {if speaker_media}
            {speaker_media}
                {if speaker_video}
                    <a class="btn" href="{speaker_video}">Video</a>
                {/if}
                {if speaker_audio}
                    <a class="btn" href="{speaker_audio}">Download MP3</a>
                {/if}
            {/speaker_media}
        {/if}
    {/speaker_import}
{if:else}
    {if media_video}
        <a class="btn" href="{media_video}">Video</a>
    {/if}
    {if media_audio}
        <a class="btn" href="{media_audio}">Download MP3</a>
    {/if}
{/if}
```

In case you're wondering why not just put the media files in the Speaker entry and be done... this Multimedia channel also populates our RSS for an iTunes podcast.

So... help?